# Ho to create an textbox mask to allow only text on Office Access form

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-office

When building an Access form, you can create a textbox with a mask. There are masks ready to use like MM/DD/YYYY for dates or HH:MM:SS for complete hours.

How to create a mask to allow only text with any size?

Examples:

**Allowed:**
MARK
New York

**Not allowed**
November 20
5800

Thanks.

Comment: What does "only text with any size" mean? Edit question to show examples.

Comment: @June7, edited. Thanks

Comment: And what rule does that employ - no numeric characters? I don't think Input Mask will resolve this. Probably have to use VBA in BeforeUpdate event to validate input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property *InputMask* of the textbox to a large number of "?", like:

```
?????????????????????????????
```

For other options, study the docs: [TextBox.InputMask property (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.inputmask).

Comment: Does that include spaces?

Comment: Yes: _Letter (A to Z, entry optional)._

Comment: It does indeed. I would have thought that *entry optional* meant only that the input can be shorter than the input mask.